# echo vs variable

Tags: php, optimization

Let's say I have `$variable` holding more than 500 kb info.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($selectFromTable)) 
{
   $variable .= "<p>$row[info]</p>";
}
```

or

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($selectFromTable)) 
{
   echo "<p>$row[info]</p>";
}
```

Optimization wise, is it better to `echo` the info right away than saving it to a `variable`?

I can't decide because I can't see the difference in performance because I don't know what tool to use in monitoring the response time. Any suggestion?

Even though there is not enough difference in performance, I still wanted to learn on how can I optimize my coding.

Comment: [Here you go](http://php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-usage.php).

Comment: They both can perform different purposes, if you don't need to pass the information back/around, then you can echo it out straight away.  If you want to separate your database logic from your presentation layer, then store the data in an array and pass that around.

Comment: @MehravishTemkar I'm on a trade-off. Either I will call that function above so I can reuse some info by saving them to variables OR call that function on a place where I can print it  right away. If the optimization has a huge impact then I must choose to print it.

Comment: @NigelRen you got my point. I have an option to pass the info back/around or simply echoed it right away but can't decide. I'm concern on how bot like Google crawl my site. Shall I be more concern on optimization or the re-use of info.

Comment: I tend not to optimize things like this, in my code I am more concerned with maintaining a separation of the processing and presentation layers.  Although having 500kb of data doesn't look very optimized in the first place!

Answer (score 3):

There is no significant difference in speed or memory usage between the two pieces of code you listed. They both build a new string that contains the value of `$row['info']` enclosed in a `<p>` HTML element.

You can pass each string as an individual argument to `echo`:

```
echo "<p>", $row['info'], "</p>";
```

This avoids the creation of a new string, uses less memory and runs slightly faster (the improvement speed is not significant unless you do it thousands of times in a loop).

Read about the [`echo`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) language construct.

Also please note that `$row[info]` is not correct. The correct way is `$row['info']`. It is [explained in the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.foo-bar) why.

Comment: I often use $row[info] than $row['info'] because it is easier and it is working fine on me. Shall I switch to $row['info']?

Comment: Have you read the documentation? It explains why `$row[info]` is incorrect. It generates a notice in PHP 5 and PHP 7.0 and 7.1. It [generates a warning since PHP 7.2](http://php.net/manual/en/migration72.deprecated.php#migration72.deprecated.unquoted-strings) and it will be upgraded to an error (because it is an error) in PHP 8.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something with variable, instead of just saving some data in it in the first loop.

With your current setup first loop with only variable storage will always be faster as operation with IO (input/output) devices are slow that means echo to print output in screen.

But if you add an echo after the variable statement then, loop with only single echo will obviously be faster.